# missing zero in cents on one field javascript

Tags: javascript

there is one form field that is missing the zero in the cents. the form field is total.

the others are ok ( total_t and total_tax work fine ). i have tried a few things but it either stops working or just doesnt add the zero on the end of the calculation.

example being if a product is 0.20 it shows as 0.2 and misses the zero on the end in the total field. but the tax and after tax work fine

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){


        $('.input-qty').on('input', function(){
            var total = 0;

            var qty = $(this).val();
            var price_single = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.input-price-single').val();

            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.input-price-total').val(parseFloat(qty * price_single).toFixed(2));

            $('.input-price-total').each(function(){
               total += Number($(this).val());
            });

            total_t = Number(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
            total_tax = parseFloat((total_t * 0.10) + total_t).toFixed(2);

            $('.input-total').val(total_t);
            $('.input-total-tax').val(total_tax);
        });

    });
</script>
```

so i guess it would be this section here:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.input-price-total').val(parseFloat(qty * price_single).toFixed(2));

            $('.input-price-total').each(function(){
               total += Number($(this).val());
```

Comment: because `.toFixed(2)` return `string`.

Comment: im not sure i understand your answer  :(

Comment: Where is the code that displays the total? It needs to use `total.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `parseFloat()` when something is already a number.

Comment: BTW: you don't have to execute `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` over and over.  Assign that to a variable, like `$parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent()`, then you can simply say `$parent.find('.input-price-single').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things 'wrong' with your code. (And it's all in your comment section too).

I'll try to fix them putting the answers together (but the credits really go to the people who suggested it.)

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('.input-qty').on('input', function(){
            var total = 0;
            var qty = $(this).val();
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
            var price_single = $(parent).find('.input-price-single').val();

            $(parent).find('.input-price-total').val((qty * price_single).toFixed(2));

            $('.input-price-total').each(function(){
               total += Number($(this).val());
            });

            $('.input-total').val(total.toFixed(2));
            $('.input-total-tax').val((total * 1.10).toFixed(2));
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't have the corresponding HTML for this, so I can't try it on a fiddle or anything, so this is solely from the top of my head. (Untested)

Your error rests in the lines:

```
total_t = Number(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
$('.input-total').val(total_t);
```

In these lines, you assign the result of your total-calculation parsed to a float, parsed to a string and then cast to a number (and that's where the real problem sits).

That means, instead of assigning a string (with the correct amount of digits) to the field, you're assigning a variable of type 'number', which assumes the formatting it deems as 'right'.

Now, if you don't want to take all my corrections (after all they're quite a few and also untested), you might roll with something like:

```
total_t = Number(parseFloat(total));
$('.input-total').val(total_t.toFixed(2));
```

This should fix your problem.